# Having problems on positioning of Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a problem on displaying 3 Bootstrap columns in the ContentArea. 
When I use Developer tools I can find them, they are at the bottom of the ContentArea, out of sight. I have tried adding the top attribute, and even the margin-top attribute but can't get those columns to move up into view in the ContentArea.

Can someone point out to me where I am going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu-toggle').toggleClass('menu-hidden');

    $('#menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
        //alert();
        $('#SidebarWrapper').toggleClass('menu-hidden');
        $('#ContentArea').toggleClass('content-grew');
        $('#SubCategories').toggleClass('slide-left');

    });
});
```

```css
body {
}
#TheLayoutContainer {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:pink;
    left:0px;
}

#menu-toggle {
    
}

#SidebarWrapper {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2000;
    background-color:black;
    transition:1s;
}

#SidebarWrapper.menu-hidden {
    width:50px;
    transition:1s;
}


#ContentArea {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    z-index: 2000;
    left: 325px;
    margin-top:0px;
    transition:1s;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#ContentArea #SubCategories {
    margin-left:-125px;
    width:125px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #72cad3;
    background-color:#72cad3;
}

#SubCategories.slide-left {
    margin-left:-75px;
    width:125px;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid #72cad3;
    background-color:#72cad3;
}

#ContentArea.content-grew {
    height: 100%;
    left: 175px;
    transition:1s;
}

#HeaderControlMenu {
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2000;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div id="HeaderControlMenu">
        <button id="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-success">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="TheLayoutContainer">

    <div id="SidebarWrapper">

    </div>

    <div id="ContentArea">
        <div id="SubCategories">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid green">A</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid green">B</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid green">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: from the doc `In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Temani Afif said, you need to enclose the parent (element that contains the rows) in an element with class `container`.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="HeaderControlMenu">
        <button id="menu-toggle" class="btn btn-success">Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="TheLayoutContainer">

    <div id="SidebarWrapper">

    </div>

    <div id="ContentArea">
        <div id="SubCategories">

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid green">A</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid green">B</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="border:1px solid green">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/p14wokz7/2/)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Because none of the other answers and comments have mentioned **all** of the mistakes in your code, I will do that in my answer:

1. Don't use "naked" rows in Bootstrap. Do this instead: If you need a *full-width* container, use a `div` (or another suitable element like `section` etc.) with the class `.container-fluid`. Otherwise, use a div with the class `.container` and put your row(s) inside that container.
2. A Bootstrap `.row` must always have at least one Bootstrap column (`.col-*`) inside and all of your content must reside inside columns. Don't put any content directly into a `.row`.
3. `.col-xs-*` classes don't exist in Bootstrap 4 (anymore). Use `.col-*` instead.
4. Replace `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` with `col-12` because that will do the exact same job. (because Bootstrap 4 is "mobile-first")
5. Replace `col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4` with `col-4` because that will do the exact same job.

Side note: You can put some content directly into a Bootstrap `.container` or `.container-fluid` i.e. without using Bootstrap rows and columns. However, that would make sense only in a few special cases because *usually* your content wouldn't be responsive if you'd do that. The exceptions to this rule are things like Bootstrap navbars and jumbotrons.